# Update nvarchar value with GETDATE results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, update, type-conversion

I would like to be able to update an `nvarchar` column with `GETDATE()`.

e.g. if the value is currently 'ordered', I need to append the date.

I did try :

```
update order_line
set comments = 'ordered'+ getdate ()
where ol_number = 10
```

but I received the error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Is there a best method of achieving this please?

Answer (score 3):

You should `CAST` the date to a *string type*, otherwise, the `+` operator tries to make an erroneous implicit cast (it is actually trying to convert `'ordered'` into a datetime, to add it to the `getdate()`):

```
update order_line
set comments = N'ordered ' + CAST(getdate() AS nvarchar(30))
where ol_number = 10 ;
```

and will result in:

```
SELECT * FROM order_line ;
GO
```

```
ol_number | comments                   
--------: | :--------------------------
       10 | ordered Jul 29 2017  5:34PM
```

You can check it at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=308389e109710de5c1f8b1b391a44428)*

Comment: Made an edit, as the question says the column is `nvarchar`, not `varchar`. You could also add explicit options/styles for the cast, using `convert()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

So if comments = N'ordered' you want to append GETDATE() ?

```
UPDATE order_line
SET comments = N'ordered '+ CAST(GETDATE() AS NVARCHAR(30))
where ol_number = 10 AND comments = N'ordered'
```